# Script tag contents are printing in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jqgrid

I'm new to Rails. I'm using jQuery and jQGrid in the project. The problem I facing is when I load the page the following contents are displaying in the page. I don't know what is the reason. Can any one tell me the reason for this problem.

```
<script src="/javascripts/jqgrid/jquery.js?1331713080" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jqgrid/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js?1331713080" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jqgrid/jquery.layout.js?1331713080" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jqgrid/i18n/grid.locale-en.js?1331713080" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jqgrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js?1331713080" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jqgrid/jquery.tablednd.js?1331713080" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jqgrid/jquery.contextmenu.js?1331713080" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is my view code ,

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "process_mon/style" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "process_mon/conf" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "prototype" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "process_mon/monitor" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "process_mon/validations"%>
<style>
        fieldset{
                font-family: Times New Roman;
                font-size: 12;
        }
        body {
                background : #f9f9f3;
        }        
.tabmenu a, #tabmenu a.active {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E6B662;
        color: #000000;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 3px 8px 1px;
        text-decoration: none;
}    
.tabmenu a:link
{
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E6B662;
        color:#000000;
        font:bold 14px arial;
        padding:5px 8px 5px 5px;
        text-decoration : none;
}
.tabmenu a.active
{
        background : none repeat scroll 0 0 #F9F9F3;
        border-bottom : 3px solid #F9F9F3;
        color : #000000;
}
#navigation ul
{
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0
}
.tabmenu li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type:none;
float: left;
margin: 0;
margin-left : -41px;
margin-right: 45px;
}
</style>

<% if params["load"] == "conf" %>
        <body onLoad="new Ajax.Updater('maindiv', '/processmonitoring/conflist', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true});return false;">
<% else %>
        <body onLoad="new Ajax.Updater('maindiv', '/processmonitoring/monitor', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true});return false;">
<% end %>
<div id="tabmenu" class="tabmenu" style="position: absolute;width : 100%">
<ul id="navigation">
                       <li><span><%= link_to "Monitor", :update => "maindiv" ,:url => { :controller => 'processmonitoring', :action => 'monitor'  },  :complete => 'reset();',  :method => 'get'  %></span></li>

                       <li><span><%= link_to "Configuration", :update => "maindiv" , :load => "conf" ,  :url => { :controller => 'processmonitoring', :action => 'conflist' } %><span></li>

</ul>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<div style="clear:both" ></div>
<div id="maindiv">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What does the view look like at the point where you're adding those scripts? Are they included verbatim or from a helper?

Comment: Could you please post your view code?

Comment: if you're seeing html code of page instead of page it means that you have wrong content type.

Comment: @iafonov : Can you please explain in detail

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but it could save some time for others:

I had the same problem today and I had a style in CSS which was the root cause:

```
body * {
   display: inline; // or any display value other than none
}
```

`*` includes `script` tag also.

Comment: Sir, can you plz explain the solution...?

Comment: @LoveToCode `script` tag is affected by css just like other tags. `display: none` is browser default for script tag. If you select `script` tag and apply css, then it would be work. As @Pho3nixHun said, `*` includes `script` tag also.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure about this but can you put your entire data in between  tags and put all your style and javascript tags between , and check if that helps

make sure you follow this pattern for your page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Web page title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- HTML code here -->
</body>
</html>
```